# Memory leakage in a dynamic size database

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Ive tried creating a dynamic database in which the user inputs the size of the database they want to create however im getting a memory leak after a certain amount of size inputs and im unsure what im doing incorrectly as im freeing everything as it should.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _product_t
{
    char *product;
    float price;
} product_t;

product_t *newDatabase(product_t *database, int *dbSize, int newSize)
{
    product_t *newdatabase = (product_t *)malloc(sizeof(*newdatabase) * newSize);

    if (newSize < *dbSize)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= newSize; i++)
        {
            if (database[i].product != NULL)
            {
                free(database[i].product);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= *dbSize; i++)
        {
            if (database[i].product != NULL)
            {
                free(database[i].product);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = *dbSize; i < newSize; i++)
    {
        // newdatabase[i].product = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        newdatabase[i].product = NULL;
        newdatabase[i].price = -1;
    }

    *dbSize = newSize;
    free(database);
    return newdatabase;
}
int main(void)
{
    product_t *database = NULL;
    int dbSize = 0;
    char cmd;
    do
    {
        printf("Command?");
        scanf(" %c", &cmd);
        switch (cmd)
        {

        case 'q':
            printf("Bye!");

            break;
        case 'n':
            printf("Size? ");
            int newSize2 = 0;
            scanf("%d", &newSize2);
            if (newSize2 < 0)
            {
                printf("Must be larger than 0");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                database = newDatabase(database, &dbSize, newSize2);
                break;
            }
        default:
            printf("Unkown command '%c'\n", cmd);
        }
    } while (cmd != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

#edit number 3
Ive opted on removing the malloc for the product pointer and decided to free all non NULL values with if and else statements

Comment: Please reformat your code so it's readable.  Also, please clarify the steps to reproduce the leak ("after a certain amount of size" makes no sense to me).

Comment: Well when I run the code it asks me for the size and I give it 10, afterwards I give it another 10 and then it suddenly stops

Comment: You attempt to access the memory pointed to by database after you have freed it. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: Well I want to free the previous database that was used which is why I free it at the begining

Comment: Programming is a matter of writing code that performs operations in a logical, sensible sequence. Look at your function. You `free()` the old instance, then go on to use that old instance attempting to `free()` pointers it contains. This is not allowed. Take a deep breath and CAREFULLY read your code...

Answer (score 1):

1. With the first malloc you allocate newSize pointers to product_t but you want to allocate an array of them instead:

```
    product_t *newdatabase = malloc(newSize * sizeof *newdatabase);
```

2. You cannot deference the database pointer after you free it.
3. Why do you only free database[i].product for i >= newSize?  Presumably you want to free all of them (but see realloc and code sample below).
4. Consider using `realloc()` to resize an array.  If it was successful your old will be retained.
5. It's clumsy having client remember the previous database size, so consider creating a struct to old both the data and the size.
6. As you allocate fixed length string, it's easier to encode that in the type.  Use constants (`PRODUCT_LEN`) instead of hard-coding magic values.
7. `malloc()` / `realloc()` of `0` bytes is implementation defined.  My implementation returns a NULL so handling it as a special case.
8. `malloc()` does not guarantee initialized memory so either initialize it after or use calloc.
9. We don't cast void * (result from malloc) in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRODUCT_LEN 100

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    char (*products)[PRODUCT_LEN];
    float *prices;
} database;

database *newDatabase() {
    return calloc(1, sizeof(database));
}

database *resizeDatabase(database *db, size_t newSize) {
    if(!db) return NULL;
    database tmp;
    tmp.products = realloc(db->products, newSize * sizeof *db->products);
    if(newSize && !tmp.products) {
        printf("realloc of products failed\n");
        // handle error
        return NULL;
    }
    db->products = tmp.products;
    tmp.prices = realloc(db->prices, newSize * sizeof *db->prices);
    if(newSize && !tmp.prices) {
        printf("realloc of prices failed\n");
        // handle error; we successfully resize products but failed
        // to resize price.  So we may need to shrink products but
        // what if that now fails?
        return NULL;
    }
    db->prices = tmp.prices;
    for(size_t i = db->size; i < newSize; i++) {
        db->products[i][0] = '\0';
        db->prices[i] = -1;
    }
    db->size = newSize;
    return db;
}

void freeDatabase(database *db) {
    if(!db) return;
    free(db->products);
    free(db->prices);
    free(db);
}

int main(void) {
    database *db = newDatabase();
    size_t tests[] = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 };
    size_t tests_len = sizeof tests / sizeof *tests;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tests_len; i++) {
        database *newDb = resizeDatabase(db, tests[i]);
        if(!newDb) {
            printf("resizefailed %zu\n", tests[i]);
            return 1;

        }
        db = newDb;
    }
    freeDatabase(db);
}
```

and here is the valgrind run:

```
==533946== HEAP SUMMARY:
==533946==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==533946==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 440 bytes allocated
==533946== 
==533946== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: I dont know how to use realloc but ive tried following your other suggestions, I hope you get to see my modified code.

Answer (score -1):

Newer version to compare to

```
#include <stdio.h>
            #include <string.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>


            typedef struct _product_t {
                char *product;
                float price;
            } product_t;


            product_t *newDatabase(product_t *database, int *dbSize, int newSize) {

    for (int i = 0; i < *dbSize; i++) {
        if (database[i].product != NULL) {
            free(database[i].product);
        }
   }
// Free the previous memory allocated for the database


                // Free the previous memory allocated for the database
                free(database);

                // Allocate new space for newSize products on the heap
                database = (product_t*) malloc(newSize * sizeof(product_t));

                // Initialize all products in the database with NULL and -1
                for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
                    database[i].product = NULL;
                    database[i].price = -1;
                }

                // Update the database size
                *dbSize = newSize;

                // Return the pointer to the new database
                return database;
            }
            int main(void) {
                product_t *database = NULL;
                int dbSize = 0;
                char cmd;
                do{
                    printf("Command?");
                    scanf(" %c", &cmd);
                    switch (cmd) {

                    case 'q':
                        printf("Bye!");

                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        printf("Size? ");
                        int newSize2 = 0;
                        scanf("%d", &newSize2);
                        if(newSize2 < 0) {
                            printf("Must be larger than 0");
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                        database = newDatabase(database, &dbSize, newSize2);
                        break;
                        }
                    default:
                        printf("Unkown command '%c'\n",cmd);
                        }
                }while(cmd != 'q');
                return 0;

            }
```

Comment: Delete this answer and edit your question instead.

Comment: big issue here. You will surely allocate memory for the field 'product', when you delete 'database' you also need to delete any memory allocated within  it. Also you throw away the old contents of the db, this is surely not what you want,. Both these mean its better to use realloc